# CSS class not apply in IE8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I use CSS for div tag in html. This is show below.

```
.sqmenu{ width:120px;
display:inline-block;
 height:80px;
 border-radius:10px;
 margin:15px 0 0px 45px;
 box-shadow:#333 2px 2px 20px;
-webkit-transform:scale(1);
transform:scale(1);
color:#093; 
-webkit-transition: ease-in-out 0.6s;
-moz-transition: ease-in-out 0.6s;
-o-transition: ease-in-out 0.6s;
-ms-transition: ease-in-out 0.6s;
transition: ease-in-out 0.6s;}

.sqmenu:hover{-webkit-transform:scale(1.2);

transform:scale(1.2);
color:#F63; 
-webkit-transition: ease-in-out 0.6s;
-moz-transition: ease-in-out 0.6s;
-o-transition: ease-in-out 0.6s;
-ms-transition: ease-in-out 0.6s;
transition: ease-in-out 0.6s;
}
```

This two class use for this line:

```
<div class="nev_menu">

        <div class="sqmenu" style="background-color:#aa68aa;">
        <a href="ourdelight.html"><div style="text-align:center; margin-top:10px;"><img src="images/Activities60.png" class="linkimg" /></div></a>
        <div style="text-align:center;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size:16px; margin-top:30px;text-decoration:none;">Our Delight</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This div is perfectly runnig in Chrome and FF & IE10 but Not running in IE8. Problem is hover and box-shadow effect not apply.

Comment: Those CSS3 properties aren't supported in IE8.

Comment: jsfiddle would be helpful...

Comment: check all div are properly closed or not

Answer (score 1):

There are several css properties that are not supported in ie8, including the box-shadow.  The hover property for ie only works if the link has an associated href.  One option that I have used in the past to help with ie8 compatibility with newer css3, is PIE - http://css3pie.com/.  It's fairly easy to implement and allows you to use the newer css3 properties like box-shadow.

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 Transitions are [not supported](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions) prior to IE10.

Answer (score 0):

for ie9 u forget : -ms-

```
transform:scale(1.2);
-ms-transform:scale(1.2);
```

But ie9 don't support "transition". For ie older version u need to use filter for transform property. Look this link :
[link](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/)